# How to remove duplicated special char in Java?

Tags: java, string, special-characters

i have String in java:
"bOcfAzr@*}Cl~Aa*@pO}p@zIgW|TkJjSoW|Ysk@nD}o@zQeRdN_`@j`AyYvs@{zA~mCce@~x@{\\t]gi@jUce@fBmm@gO"

And i would like to change all duplicates "\\" to one "\".

Replace function does not work on special characters :(
How can i do that?

Comment: Make sure you escape it correctly: `string = string.replace("\\\\", "\\");`

Comment: i do this and it does not work :((

Comment: @JacekKaczmarek Then please show the code you have tried.

Comment: @JacekKaczmarek  Strings are immutable.  Are  you assigning the result of replace back into a String variable?  It won't change the existing string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `replace("\\\\", "\\")` should replace all backlashes:

```java
String input = "bOcfAzr@}Cl~Aa@pO}p@zIgW|TkJjSoW|Ysk@nD}o@zQeRdN_@jAyYvs@{zA~mCce@~x@{\\\\t]gi@jUce@fBmm@gO\\\\";
System.out.println("input: " + input);
String replaced = input.replace("\\\\", "\\");
System.out.println(replaced);
```

Above code prints the following output:

```
input: bOcfAzr@}Cl~Aa@pO}p@zIgW|TkJjSoW|Ysk@nD}o@zQeRdN_@jAyYvs@{zA~mCce@~x@{\\t]gi@jUce@fBmm@gO\\
bOcfAzr@}Cl~Aa@pO}p@zIgW|TkJjSoW|Ysk@nD}o@zQeRdN_@jAyYvs@{zA~mCce@~x@{\t]gi@jUce@fBmm@gO\
```